# <%: %> brackets for HTML Encoding in ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, webforms, .net-4.0, html-encode

Accidentally I found [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx) about a new feature in ASP.NET 4.0: Expressions enclosed in these new brackets `<%: Content %>` should be rendered as HTML encoded.

I've tried this within a databound label in a FormView like so:

```
<asp:Label ID="MyLabel" runat="server" Text='<%: Eval("MyTextProperty") %>' />
```

But it doesn't work: The text property contains script tags (for testing), but the output is blank. Using the traditional way works:

```
<asp:Label ID="MyLabel" runat="server"
    Text='<%# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("MyTextProperty")) %>' />
```

What am I doing wrong?

(On a sidenote: I am too stupid to find any information: Google refuses to search for that thing. The VS2010 Online help on MSDN offers a lot of hits, but nothing related to my search. Stackoverflow search too. And I don't know how these "things" (the brackets I mean) are officially called to have a better search term.)

Any info and additional links and resources are welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sanity check 1: when you do a "view source" of the rendered page, do you see that <%: %> markup? (you shouldn't) Sanity check 2: is your site really using asp.net 4.0? This feature doesn't work in 2.0.

Comment: "Yes" and "Yes". I think, Oded is right: when I use the brackets outside of the FormView and without Eval it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confusing [data binding expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx), which have the syntax `<%#%>` and are used with `Eval` (and `Bind`) with the response output tags (`<%=%>` and `<%:%>`) that cannot be used with `Eval`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `<%#:  %>` HTML encoding databinding syntax. (Notice the ':' after the '#').  For example:

```
Text='<%#: Eval("PropertyToEval") %>'
```